# Not able to convert date to epoch time

Tags: java, datetime-format, epoch

This is my sample code

```
    String dt = "Oct 24 2019 12:00:00.000 AM UTC";
    String dt1="Oct 24 2019 11:59:59.000 PM UTC";
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS 
    aa zzz");
    Date date = df.parse(dt);
    Date date1 = df.parse(dt1);
    long epoch = date.getTime();
    long epoch1 = date1.getTime();
    System.out.println(epoch);
    System.out.println(epoch1);
```

Here specifying the AM and PM but its not taking the value for that and throwing the exception as

```
{"error_code":"INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE","message":"Time range must have a start time earlier than the end time"}
```

How to specify AM/PM in the java code.
How can I take yesterday's date and time for today in java code as an input to convert to epoch.

Comment: I just ran your code snippet and everything works for me.

Comment: Please don't use `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` classes now. They have been replaced with much better classes. Look into [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) and [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) classes.

Comment: FYI, the terribly flawed date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html) classes built into Java 8 and later.

Comment: quick look at [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) reveals that `H`, uppercase, is used for "Hours (0-23)", while `h`, lowercase, for "Hours in am/pm(1-12)"

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime
.parse(
    "Oct 24 2019 12:00:00.000 AM UTC" ,
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MMM d uuuu hh:mm:ss.SSS a z" ).withLocale( Locale.US ) 
)
.toInstant() 
.toEpochMilli()
```

> 1571875200000

## *java.time*

Two problems:

- As [commented by Heuberger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58553678/not-able-to-convert-date-to-epoch-time/58553984#comment103427339_58553678), you are using incorrect formatting codes.
- You are using terrible date-time classes supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes.

Your inputs, renamed for clarity.

```
String inputStart = "Oct 24 2019 12:00:00.000 AM UTC";
String inputStop = "Oct 24 2019 11:59:59.000 PM UTC";
```

Define a formatting pattern to match your inputs.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MMM d uuuu hh:mm:ss.SSS a z" ).withLocale( Locale.US );
```

Parse inputs.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtStart = ZonedDateTime.parse( inputStart , f );
ZonedDateTime zdtStop = ZonedDateTime.parse( inputStop , f );
```

Calculate elapsed time. We should get one second less than 24 hours.

```
Duration d = Duration.between( zdtStart , zdtStop );
```

Apparently you want the count of milliseconds since the epoch reference of first moment of 1970 in UTC, 1970-01-01T00:00Z. First extract the building-block class, `Instant`, from each `ZonedDateTime`. An `Instant` represents a moment in UTC. This class lets you interrogate for the count since epoch. Note that *java.time* classes resolve to nanoseconds. So asking for milliseconds can result in data loss, ignoring any microseconds or nanoseconds.

```
Instant start = zdtStart.toInstant() ;
Instant stop = zdtStop.toInstant() ;

long millisStart = start.toEpochMilli() ;
long milliStop = stop.toEpochMilli() ;
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "zdtStart = " + zdtStart );
System.out.println( "zdtStop = " + zdtStop );
System.out.println( "d = " + d );

System.out.println( "start = " + start );
System.out.println( "stop = " + stop );

System.out.println( "millisStart = " + millisStart );
System.out.println( "milliStop = " + milliStop );
```

> zdtStart = 2019-10-24T00:00Z[UTC]
>
> zdtStop = 2019-10-24T23:59:59Z[UTC]
>
> d = PT23H59M59S
>
> start = 2019-10-24T00:00:00Z
>
> stop = 2019-10-24T23:59:59Z
>
> millisStart = 1571875200000
>
> milliStop = 1571961599000

---

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the following date format:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS a zzz",Locale.US);
```

For AM/PM Marker, 'a' is used. For [reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

e.g.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            String dt = "Oct 24 2019 12:00:00.000 AM UTC";
            String dt1="Oct 24 2019 11:59:59.000 PM UTC";
            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS a zzz",Locale.US);
            Date date = df.parse(dt);
            Date date1 = df.parse(dt1);
            long epoch = date.getTime();
            long epoch1 = date1.getTime();
            System.out.println(epoch);
            System.out.println(epoch1);  
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
1571918400000                                                                                                                                                                      
1571918399000
```

Comment: You should also add second parameter to `new SimpleDateFormat` with value `Locale.US`, otherwise parsing may fail, since `Oct` would be an unknown month in most other languages.

Comment: How can 1 second before midnight on 24th be 1 second before midnight on the 24th? There is 23 hours, 59 minutes, 59 seconds from midnight (start of day) to 1 second before midnight (end of day). When I run your code, I get `1571875200000` and `1571961599000`